# Improving query performance - DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, db2, query-optimization

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to write a query in DB2. But I think its rather inefficient as it takes more resources. Would really appreciate, if someone can provide any suggestion which can make below query more efficient. I understand that it would require to know the actual requirement/system knowledge to provide better advise, but on a first look, if you guys think something is messed up, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
DK.

```
SELECT LIF.EMPID, LIF.BPA_NR , YEAR(LIF.BEG_DTE) ,MONTH(LIF.BEG_DTE) ,LIF.TFIDZ
     , LVA.TRFIDZ, UZA.TRFIDZ, YEAR(LIF.BEG_DTE) - YEAR(KAR.DOB)
     , ((YEAR(APK.TERMDT) - YEAR(APK.BEGDAT)) * 12 + MONTH(APK.TERMDT) - MONTH(APK.BEGDAT))
     , KAR.DTHSUM, LVA.LVAGELD,  UZA.UZAGELD,  APK.EMIRKA
     , LVA.EMILVA, UZA.EMIUZA , APK.EPROM, LVA.EPROM, UZA.EPROM
     , LIF.LOANNR ,LIF.SUMAMT , MONTH(JOU.ZDATE), YEAR(JOU.ZDATE)
     , (YEAR(JOU.ZDATE) - YEAR(APK.BEGDAT))*12 + MONTH(JOU.ZDATE) - MONTH(APK.BEGDAT)
     , COALESCE(JOU.TYP,'OTH') , COALESCE(PRO1.BOOKEMI,0)
     , COALESCE(PRO2.BOOKEMI,0),COALESCE(PRO3.BOOKEMI,0)                  
FROM DEVDBA.LIFE LIF                                                    
LEFT OUTER JOIN (                                                         
    SELECT ( CASE WHEN JU6.REASN = 'AAA' 
                   AND NOT EXISTS (
                      SELECT 1 FROM DEVDBA.LOGTBL JU7             
                      WHERE JU7.EMPID=JU6.EMPID 
                        AND JU7.GANID>JU6.GANID     
                        AND JU7.ZDATE=JU6.ZDATE 
                        AND JU7.REASN='BBB'
                   ) THEN 'KRE'
                  WHEN JU6.REASN IN ('EEE','DDD') 
                     THEN 'SON'                   
                  ELSE 'OTH'                                                     
               END) AS TYP
         , JU6.EMPID, JU6.REASN, JU6.ZDATE, JU6.GANID     
    FROM DEVDBA.LOGTBL JU6                                            
    WHERE JU6.REASN IN ('AAA','EEE','DDD')                            
) JOU                                                               
    ON LIF.EMPID = JOU.EMPID                                  
   AND LIF.ZUNID = JOU.GANID                                  
LEFT OUTER JOIN DEVDBA.LVAGR LVA                                   
    ON JOU.EMPID = LVA.EMPID                                  
   AND JOU.GANID = LVA.ZUNID                                  
LEFT OUTER JOIN DEVDBA.UZAGR UZA                                   
    ON JOU.EMPID = UZA.EMPID                                  
   AND JOU.GANID = UZA.ZUNID                                  
LEFT OUTER JOIN DEVDBA.APKGR APK                                   
    ON  JOU.EMPID = APK.EMPID                                  
   AND JOU.GANID = APK.ZUNID                                  
LEFT OUTER JOIN DEVDBA.KARGR KAR                                  
    ON  JOU.EMPID = KAR.EMPID                                  
   AND JOU.GANID = KAR.ZUNID                                  
LEFT OUTER JOIN (                                                   
    SELECT PR1.EMPID, PR1.GANID, PR1.BOOKEMI      
    FROM DEVDBA.COMMS PR1, DEVDBA.LOGTBL JU1                   
    WHERE PR1.PROVART IN ('789')                             
      AND PR1.EMPID = JU1.EMPID                            
      AND PR1.GANID = JU1.GANID                            
) PRO1                                                   
    ON  JOU.EMPID = PRO1.EMPID                           
   AND JOU.GANID = PRO1.GANID                           
LEFT OUTER JOIN (                                             
    SELECT PR3.EMPID, PR3.GANID, PR3.BOOKEMI
    FROM DEVDBA.COMMS PR3, DEVDBA.LOGTBL JU3             
    WHERE PR3.PROVART IN ('123')                             
      AND PR3.EMPID = JU3.EMPID                            
      AND PR3.GANID = JU3.GANID                            
) PRO2                                                   
    ON  JOU.EMPID = PRO2.EMPID                           
   AND JOU.GANID = PRO2.GANID                           
LEFT OUTER JOIN (                                             
    SELECT PR5.EMPID, PR5.GANID, PR5.BOOKEMI
    FROM DEVDBA.COMMS PR5, DEVDBA.LOGTBL JU5             
    WHERE PR5.PROVART IN ('456')                             
      AND PR5.EMPID = JU5.EMPID                            
      AND PR5.GANID = JU5.GANID                            
) PRO3                                                   
    ON  JOU.EMPID = PRO3.EMPID                           
    AND JOU.GANID = PRO3.GANID                           
WHERE LIF.BPA_NR IN ('001','002') 
  AND JOU.TYP <> 'OTH'  
  AND LIF.BEG_DTE BETWEEN '01.01.2022' AND '31.12.2099'
ORDER BY LIF.BPA_NR,LIF.EMPID WITH UR;
```

Comment: Why do you think it is inefficient and what is your definition of efficient? In order to get help with query performance you need to show the EXPLAIN PLAN for your query, table definitions (including indexes) and record counts for the tables

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: The requested info was not provided in 24 hours so voting to close.

Comment: @TheImpaler: Hi, I am looking suggestions like the one provided by Mr. lennart below,  in the way my query has been written as that would be worth trying to see if it can make any difference.

Comment: @NickW. Hi, I ran the query in QMF, it was taking 20-30 secs to execute the query and QMF has calculated the cost of Query as 285. However I have no idea what would be the ideal run time and cost. So I just want to hear from experts if there is any way I can reduce/improvise the JOINs in my query so that I can try it out and see if there is any improvement or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer per se, but it is to long for a comment so I'll add it here anyhow.

Diffiult to say much without knowing more details. You should start by looking at the access plan. I find [db2caem](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-db2caem-capture-activity-event-monitor-data-tool) to be very good since it outputs both estimated cardinality and actual cardinality for each operator. If there is a big difference in an operator it is usually a hint on where to start investigating.

db2advis kan give you some hints about missing indexes, but don't take it's word for granted, it often suggests redundant indexes so you have to investigate what it recomends. If you don't have access to db2advis, you might want to try:

[Index Advisor](https://github.com/lelle1234/Db2Utils/blob/master/IndexAdvisor/index_advisor.py)

It is a python script that generates the same set of index candidates as db2advis, and then evaluates the powerset of index combinations and their estimated improvements, and picks the best 1-index, 2-index, ..., n-index combinations. The cardinality of a powerset grows quickly so one can set an lower- and upper- bound for what index combinations to investigate. Use at your own risk

Some observations about the code it-self. In the past I have seen some mysterious effects in the optimizer when mixing "comma"-joins and ansi-joins. I suggest you replace constructions like:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (                                                   
    SELECT PR1.EMPID, PR1.GANID, PR1.BOOKEMI      
    FROM DEVDBA.COMMS PR1, DEVDBA.LOGTBL JU1                   
    WHERE PR1.PROVART IN ('789')                             
      AND PR1.EMPID = JU1.EMPID                            
      AND PR1.GANID = JU1.GANID                            
) PRO1
```

with:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (                                                   
    SELECT PR1.EMPID, PR1.GANID, PR1.BOOKEMI      
    FROM DEVDBA.COMMS PR1
    JOIN DEVDBA.LOGTBL JU1
        ON PR1.EMPID = JU1.EMPID                            
       AND PR1.GANID = JU1.GANID                    
    WHERE PR1.PROVART IN ('789')                             
) PRO1
```

You seems to be repeating the same join in PRO1, PRO2 and PRO3:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (                                                   
    SELECT PR1.EMPID, PR1.GANID, PR1.BOOKEMI      
    FROM DEVDBA.COMMS PR1, DEVDBA.LOGTBL JU1                   
    WHERE PR1.PROVART IN ('789')                             
      AND PR1.EMPID = JU1.EMPID                            
      AND PR1.GANID = JU1.GANID                            
) PRO1                                                   
    ON  JOU.EMPID = PRO1.EMPID                           
   AND JOU.GANID = PRO1.GANID                           
LEFT OUTER JOIN (                                             
    SELECT PR3.EMPID, PR3.GANID, PR3.BOOKEMI
    FROM DEVDBA.COMMS PR3, DEVDBA.LOGTBL JU3             
    WHERE PR3.PROVART IN ('123')                             
      AND PR3.EMPID = JU3.EMPID                            
      AND PR3.GANID = JU3.GANID                            
) PRO2                                                   
    ON  JOU.EMPID = PRO2.EMPID                           
    AND JOU.GANID = PRO2.GANID 
...
```

You may want to investigate if you can rephrase to something like:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (                                                   
    SELECT PR1.EMPID, PR1.GANID, PR1.BOOKEMI, PR1.PROVART      
    FROM DEVDBA.COMMS PR1
    JOIN DEVDBA.LOGTBL JU1
        ON PR1.EMPID = JU1.EMPID                            
       AND PR1.GANID = JU1.GANID                    
    WHERE PR1.PROVART IN ('789', '123', '456')                             
) PRO
    ON  JOU.EMPID = PRO.EMPID                           
   AND JOU.GANID = PRO.GANID
```

and then use a case expression over PROVART in your select to track the origin of the result

Occationally it can also help to manually push the join predicates into a  derived table using LATERAL

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (                                                   
    SELECT PR1.EMPID, PR1.GANID, PR1.BOOKEMI, PR1.PROVART      
    FROM DEVDBA.COMMS PR1
    JOIN DEVDBA.LOGTBL JU1
        ON PR1.EMPID = JU1.EMPID                            
       AND PR1.GANID = JU1.GANID                    
    WHERE PR1.PROVART IN ('789', '123', '456')                             
      AND JOU.EMPID = PR1.EMPID                           
      AND JOU.GANID = PR1.GANID 
) PRO
    ON  JOU.EMPID = PRO.EMPID                           
   AND JOU.GANID = PRO.GANID
```

Just some thoughts.

Comment: Hi @Lennart, Thanks. I would try it out and post here if it makes any improvements.